# Error from Amazon Webstore img and li must have no character?

Tags: amazon-web-services

The element type "li" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

Invalid XML: The element type "li" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

Images example:

```
<ul class="left">
<li class="title">Customer Service</li>
<li class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.sample.com/contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://sample.com/info/shipping/ref=shop-global-footer">Shipping</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://sample.com/info/returns/ref=shop-global-footer">Returns</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="pad-left">
        <li><a href="https://sample.com/info/FAQ/ref=shop-global-footer">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://sample.com/info/sizeGuide/ref=shop-global-footer">Size Guide</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.sample.com/DMCA.html">DMCA Statement</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
    <ul class="mid">
<li class="title">My Account</li>
<li class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="https://sample.com/youraccount/ref=shop-global-footer">My Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://sample.com/signin/ref=shop-global-footer">Login</a>    </li>
        <li><a href="https://sample.com/signin?pageFlowType=CREATE_NEW_ACCOUNT_MAIN/ref=shop-global-footer">Create</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://sample.com/vieworders/ref=shop-global-footer">Track Your Order</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
<ul class="right">
<li class="title">Connect</li>
<li class="menu social">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="facebook" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/F"><img alt="Facebook" src="/media/Site Files/Theme Files/Active Theme/Images/common/1pixel.gif"></img>Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/"><img alt="Twitter" src="/media/Site Files/Theme Files/Active Theme/Images/common/1pixel.gif"></img>Twitter</a></li>
        <li class="email"><a rel=".newsletter-modal" class="email-footer" href="#"><img alt="Newsletter" src="/media/Site Files/Theme Files/Active Theme/Images/common/1pixel.gif"></img>Email</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've doubled-up your closing `</ul>` tags near the end of the document. It might also be helpful to run your snippet through an [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org).